# JavaScript animations not working (no button flash) and no audio when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on an online boot camp project and could not get my code to create the proper animation. When I press one of the colored buttons, it should flash, but nothing happens. I downloaded the solution file and it also does not work.

I also tried adding:

```js
console.log(userClickedPattern);
playSound(userChosenColor);
```

to the bottom of the:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){}
```

but that did not seem to make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "Yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
  playSound(userChosenColor);
  animatePress(userChosenColor);
});

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColor);
}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define class `pressed` also your selector for the buttons was wrong `#btn` instead of `.btn`

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "Yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
  playSound(userChosenColor);
  animatePress(userChosenColor);
});

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColor);
}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Simon</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
    <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
    <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```